# LINQ to SQL is not updating child element

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm grabbing a Cart object, which has a collection of CartItem objects. I have a function to add a CartItem object to the Cart object. If I simply call myCart.CartItems.Add(cartItem), it works fine. In the event that the item already exists in the cart, I simply want to increment the Quantity field, rather than inserting a new record. This does not work. The existing CartItem object gets updated, but calling SubmitChanges on the ProjectDataContext does not save the change. Below is the code for my AddItem function.

```
public CartItem AddItem(CartItem cartItem)
{
    CartItem existingCartItem = this.CartItems.Where(c => c.DealOptionId == cartItem.DealOptionId&& c.isGift == cartItem.isGift).FirstOrDefault();

    if (existingCartItem != null)
    {
        existingCartItem.Quantity += cartItem.Quantity;
        return existingCartItem;
    }
    else
    {
        cartItem.CartId = this.CartId;

        if (cartItem.Price == 0)
        {
            ProjectDataContext pdc = Connection.GetContext();
            DealOption dealOption = pdc.DealOptions.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Id == cartItem.DealOptionId);
            cartItem.Price = dealOption.OfferPrice;
        }

        this.CartItems.Add(cartItem);
        return cartItem;
    }
}
```

The Cart object is attached to the ProjectDataContext properly, as it will add CartItem objects without a problem. It just will not update existing ones. I'm assuming it's just a trivial misunderstanding of LINQ to SQL on my part.

**Edit:** More clarification.

That datacontext is only used for that one retrieval. The cart object has its own that works fine. Like I said, if I add a new object to the list, it works perfectly, but editing an existing one will not save to the DB. That's why I'm so confused.

I should also note that the additional ProjectDataContext below is never actually hit because of the if statement, so I know that's not interfering either.

**Added**

Here's the code that calls this function, including the ProjectDataContext

```
        ProjectDataContext pdc = Connection.GetContext();
        Model.Cart myCart = Model.Cart.GetCart(pdc);
        CartItem cartItem = new CartItem();
        DealOptionRepository dor = new DealOptionRepository(pdc);
        DealOption dealOption = dor.GetById(dealOptionId);
        cartItem.DealOptionId = dealOptionId;
        cartItem.DealId = dealOption.DealId;
        cartItem.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(hdnPrice.Value);

        cartItem.isGift = false;
        cartItem.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(ddlBFMQty.SelectedValue);

        CartItem thisItem = myCart.AddItem(cartItem);
        pdc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your code here; but is it possible you're intermingling different DataContexts?  I see lower down in your code that you get [what appears to be a new] instance of your `ProjectDataContext`.  Are you sure that `ProjectDataContext` that you used to return your `CartItem` is the same one you're calling `SaveChanges` on?

Comment: Where do you call `SubmitChanges`? Are the entity classes created by a tool or have you written them manually?

Comment: @AndersAbel This is linq-to-sql, the classes are typically generated by the designer (I dont think you have any other options do you?)

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: I've used the designer, sqlmetal.exe, handwritten code myself for custom stuff and rolled my own custom code generator. There is a T4 template from DamienG that many people use. It is also possible to use POCO classes and put the mapping in XML, so there are many options - all of them with slightly different behaviour and possibilities for different bugs.

Comment: That datacontext is only used for that one retrieval. The cart object has its own that works fine. Like I said, if I add a new object to the list, it works perfectly, but editing an existing one will not save to the DB. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: How is `this.CartItems` maintained?  Unless "this" is a ProjectDatacontext itself, this code won't add anything to your database.  Where did cartItem come from?  The only thing you're doing with pdc is snagging an OfferPrice and assigning it's value to the .Price property of the cartItem you passed in.  Where is your actual persistence taking place?

Comment: Can you create a simple piece of code that replicates this problem? We have no visibility of what `this` is, can't see where the datacontext is instantiated or where you call `SubmitChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid. I had a function in the Cart class to retrieve a cart based on id, and I forgot to remove the new DataContext in that function. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.